# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when working with structs in LLDB

Tags: xcode, crash, lldb, cgaffinetransform

Whenever I try to work with CGAffineTransform and CATransform3D structs in the Xcode debugger, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this: the problem is caused only when I return one of these structs from an Objective-C method, so I converted the key methods that return them to C functions. You can also try `expr @import UIKit` and `expr @import QuartzCore` to help.